# Python3 variable passing issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, return, try-catch

Example code, try to ignore how it is seems unnecessarily overcomplicated- this is way dumbed down from the actual code, but mimics the flow exactly.

```
def setup():
   print("Setting up...")
   do_something()

def do_something():
   task = str(input("Enter a task to do: "))
   try:
      print("Doing {}...".format(task))
   except:
      print("Failed to do {}...".format(task))
   finally:
      return task

def choose_2(choice):
   print("You chose {}".format(choice))

def menu_1():
   choice = int(input("Choose 1 or 2: "))
   if choice == 1:
      setup()
      menu_2(task)

menu_1()
```

However, the program returns "**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'task' referenced before assignment**"

Why is `do_something()` ***not*** returning the variable `task` to the `if` statement within `menu_1()`? Once `setup()` (and subsequently `do_something()`) finishes running, shouldn't `do_something()`'s returned value remain inside the `if` statement, since it's not done yet?

Comment: it is, you simply discard it. A `return` doesn't do anything except *return* a value, not a **variable** from a function. there is no `task` variable defined in `menu_1`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So return returns the *value* of the 'task' variable, not the 'task' variable itself?

Comment: Yes. Variables are *local* to functions, or can be in the global scope, or in some enclosing scope. You don't pass variables around, you pass values. Variables generally only exist for a given execution of a function. So functions that return something usually expect you to capture that value in the caller, so `returned_value = some_func()`, and it doesn't matter if `some_func` returned `foo`, because `foo` will not be defined where you called `some_func`, unless *you* do something like `foo = some_func`, but they are still two different variables

Comment: You need to capture the value returned from your functions to do something with those values, or else they simply become unreachable, and will be garbage collected if no other reference exists. Every time you call a functino that returns a value, you need to capture the value in a variable in the caller. Just like you would with any built-in function, e.g. you do `x = input(...)` right? Why don't you just do `input()`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Since this is the real answer to my issue, you can put this in an Answer and I'll mark it, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The flow is :
`menu_1() => menu_2(task)`

`task` has not been defined in the scope of `menu_1()` so it has no way of being defined.

You may have intended to do this instead:

```
def setup():
   print("Setting up...")
   return do_something()
.....
# in menu_1():
menu_2(setup())
```

Notice that because `setup` now RETURNS something, it can have that return value used.

Comment: They call `setup` in `menu_1`, which calls `do_something`, which returns `task`. Of course, `setup` doesn't return anything, but the OP has a fundamental misunderstanding of what `return` does, and variable scope

Comment: That won't fix it either. The problem is that they think that `return` will magically insert the *variable* into the callers scope.

Comment: Yeah @juanpa.arrivillaga is right- I misunderstood what 'return' does. I think I just need to rethink my overall logic/flow...

Comment: Do you think they just need to learn about how the `global` keyword works?

Comment: @JacobIRR no. `global` is a terrible practice

Comment: I've been told it's bad practice to use global vars. That'd be the easiest fix of course, but I'm trying to avoid using them.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah in that case, I think a class with references to self would help

Comment: @JacobIRR but just returning values from functions is a pretty standard and straightforward way to do things, you don't *need* a class. There is no need for conserved state here anyway. Plus, they should really learn how to use `return`

Answer (score 0):

setup() and menu_1() function should be changed like this:

```
def setup():
    print("Setting up...")
    do_something()

def menu_1():
   choice = int(input("Choose 1 or 2: "))
   if choice == 1:
       task=setup()
       menu_2(task)
```

Explanation:
menu_1() calls setup(), setup() calls do_something(). Now 'do_something()' will return the value of task but you are not returning it from 'setup()' function to menu_1() and then in menu_1() you have to store the returned value in a variable named 'task'.

Comment: 'return task' will return the value of task which you will have to either store somewhere in the calling function(setup()) or return that value to the next function present in the stack i.e.,  'menu_1()'